# MySQL 5.6 Selecting months and days

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-5.6

I am struggling to understand the date functions of MySQL.

For example, I want to get all records of this month and the previous month.

From what I understand I'm supposed to use `MONTH(NOW())` which returns the integer of the current month and `MONTH(NOW())-1` for the previous month. Except when asking for a date in January, this will obviously will not work as it's performed on the result of the function instead of wrapping around and going to December of the previous year.

How would I go about writing a generic function that would work on January too? Since months have varying lengths it wouldn't be possible to subtract a month in milliseconds from `NOW()` I recon.

For example, this query works fine except on January:

```
SELECT
          SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(table_date) = MONTH(NOW())-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LAST_MONTH,
          SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(table_date) = MONTH(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS THIS_MONTH
          FROM table
          WHERE table_date BETWEEN Date_add(NOW(), interval - 1 month) AND  NOW()
```

A similar issue arises with `DAY()` function since months have varying lengths and writing statements for each and every day doesn't seem very efficient.

What is a more efficient way of selecting the records for each day of any month of interest, regardless of whether that specific day actually has records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are vulnerable to pulling records from all years not only the current one stored within `table_date`. To get rid of it you need to operate on the year as well which can be done by always calculating on the proper date format `YYYY-MM-DD` not to lose precision.

*Here are some calculations used to build up final query.*

First day of month:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(table_date, '%Y-%m-01') FROM table
```

First day of previous month:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(table_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') FROM table
```

Last day of month:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(table_date) FROM table
```

Last day of previous month:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(table_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) FROM table
```

**Your final query:**

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN table_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(table_date, '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(table_date) THEN 1 END) AS this_month,
  SUM(CASE WHEN table_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(table_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(table_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) THEN 1 END) AS last_month
FROM table
WHERE 
  table_date BETWEEN 
   DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(table_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01')
   AND LAST_DAY(table_date)
```

Note: In the case expression I've omitted `ELSE 0` since default statement for `ELSE` in CASE is null and `SUM()` ignores null values :-)

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I got switched to a different subsystem out of nowhere. Very good breakdown of the query, crystal clear explanation and thus accepted as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is not safe also for dates from other years.
The way to achieve what you want might be to truncate the dates to the first of the month, e.g. (for replaced `NOW` with `2013-01-20`)

```
select table_date, 
case when date_format(table_date, '%Y-%m-01') 
  = date_format('2013-01-20', '%Y-%m-01') then 1 end AS THIS_MONTH,
case when date_format(table_date, '%Y-%m-01')
  = date_add(date_format('2013-01-20', '%Y-%m-01'), interval -1 month) then 1 end AS LAST_MONTH
from x;
```

See this [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7ea20/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic converts the date into integer then subtracts 1 from it. For days and month like January, the value becomes 1. From which if you subtract 1, it becomes zero, which is not a valid date or month.

For month try this: `sum(case when month(table_date) = month(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)) then 1 else 0 end) as last_month`.

You can use similar logic for days

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this :

```
SELECT table_date, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (LEFT(table_date, 7) = LEFT(NOW(),7)) THEN 
        1 
    ELSE 0 END) AS THIS_MONTH,
SUM(CASE WHEN 
    (LEFT(table_date, 7) = LEFT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),7)) THEN 
    1 ELSE 0 END) AS LAST_MONTH
FROM table
WHERE LEFT(table_date, 7) BETWEEN LEFT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),7) 
AND LEFT(NOW(),7)
```